# how to format 1700 to 1'700 and 1000000 to 1'000'000 in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, format, string-formatting

I like to format all numbers like in math. is there a predefined function or is that just possible with substring and replace?

edit: my culture is de-ch

Best regards

Comment: which language/culture is that?

Comment: For 1000000 why would you have two different group separators? Out of interest, which country are you in? I've never seen apostrophes (backwards or forwards) used for group separators - it's normally a comma, space or dot in my experience.

Comment: i don't have two... this is a mistake.. im sry

Comment: @JonSkeet It's automatically converting the apostrophes in two different ways; there doesn't appear to be a way to stop it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: In Switzerland, for example, the apostrophe is used as group separator.

Comment: @DrJokepu: Thanks - it's always nice to learn a bit more about cultural issues :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32("1700");
string result = String.Format("{0:##,##}", input);
```

Or this

```
Console.WriteLine(1700.ToString("##,##", new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberGroupSeparator = "'" }));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var numformat = new NumberFormatInfo {
                   NumberGroupSeparator = "'",
                   NumberGroupSizes = new int[] { 3 },
                   NumberDecimalSeparator = "."
                };
Console.WriteLine(1000000.ToString("N",numformat));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(1000000.ToString("#,##0").Replace(
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator, "'"));
```

Or

```
NumberFormatInfo likeInMath = new NumberFormatInfo()
{
    NumberGroupSeparator = "'"
};
Console.WriteLine(1000000.ToString("#,##0", likeInMath));
```

Comment: That doesn't work on my machine. It prints `1 000 000`. My culture is nb-NO

Comment: @Svish, just fixed that, take a look

Answer (score 0):

use [int.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa987498(VS.80).aspx) and an [iFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx).

also take a look here [msdn.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I always Use this format

```
 "#,##0;#,##0'-';0"
```

so You can use it in

```
 int input = Convert.ToInt32("100000000");  
 string result = String.Format("{#,##0;#,##0'-';0}", input);
```